# How to set the orientation of a QStyleOptionProgressBar inside a QStyledItemDelegate

Tags: c++, qt

I am using Qt 5.15.2. I have a `QTableView` that loads data from a class derived from `QAbstractTableModel`. This works well. Now I want to add a progress bar in each row of a column. To do so I've derived a class from `QStyledItemDelegate`:

```
class ProgressBarDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ProgressBarDelegate(QObject *parent = 0) : QStyledItemDelegate(parent) {}

    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const override {
        if (index.data().canConvert<int>()) {
            int progress = qvariant_cast<int>(index.data());

            QStyleOptionProgressBar progressBarOption;
            progressBarOption.rect = option.rect;
            progressBarOption.minimum = 0;
            progressBarOption.maximum = 100;
            progressBarOption.progress = progress;

            QStyle *style = QApplication::style();

            style->drawControl(QStyle::CE_ProgressBar, &progressBarOption, painter);

        } else {
            QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
        }
    }
};
```

It almost works, the problem is that the progress bar goes from bottom to top as you can see below :

[image: ProgressBarDelegate vertical orientation]

[image: Zoomed ProgressBarDelegate vertical orientation]

How can I change the orientation from left to right ?

By the way, is this the best method for populating a progress bar into a `QTableView`?

Comment: Your question in unclear. The graph goes from left to right, could you explain me better

Comment: @eyllanesc I've added another screenshot. You can clearly see that the progress bar in each row as a bad orientation. When progressing, the green rectangle fills the bar from bottom to top, instead of left to right.

Comment: mmm, It seems like that depends on the style you use, what do you get when you run `qDebug() << a.style()->metaObject()->className();`? Try with: `progressBarOption.orientation = Qt::Horizontal;` or `progressBarOption.orientation = Qt::Vertical;`

Comment: @eyllanesc `qDebug() << style->metaObject()->className();` gives `QWindowsVistaStyle`. Unfortunately, `'class QStyleOptionProgressBar' has no member named 'orientation'`

Comment: 1) try add `a.setStyle("fusion")` after `QApplication a(argv, argc);`, 2) what is your Qt Version?

Comment: @eyllanesc With `fusion` the progress bar is displayed but always at a 0% state. I am using Qt 5.15.2

Comment: Check the value of `qDebug() << qvariant_cast<int>(index.data());`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235086/discussion-between-victor-and-eyllanesc).

Answer (score 1):

The missing line is:

```
progressBarOption.state = QStyle::StateFlag::State_Horizontal;
```